# Encryption Linux system after installation

Tags: linux, debian, encryption

Is it possible to encrypt a Linux system (Mint, Debian based) **after** installation? For an "on the fly" usage.
My system is both : a client (www, ethernet), a local server (wifi).

I am working on a prototype, installing and configuring various packages and I aim to clone it onto other machines.
For now I hope to test encrypting my prototype.

I'm reading doc about dm-crypt. For a full disk encrypt (data+system). It seems I need it. At login I'll provide the passphrase.

Comment: You should be more specific in what you try to achieve exactly. Do you want to run the system from an encrypted container (for example LUKS), do you just want to store and distribute an encrypted image (which is decrypted, then deployed)? Why did you add [tag:pgp], how do you want to use it here?

Comment: pgp is deleted and edited. I edit my post. Thank you.

Comment: How are you going to generate and store the password/keyfile?

Comment: @Gilles : PenDrive (USB, or - better IMO - SD )

Comment: @JensErat : I plan to use LUKS, yes. Unless a better solution for my needs.